# Print boost strong typedef'ed type in gdb

Tags: c++, boost, gdb

I have used `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` in my code to separate different types of identifiers based on `std::string` (so that I can have `SERVER_ID` and `FILE_ID`, e.g., and don't accidentally pass the ID of a server when the function expects the ID of a file).

I am now debugging my code and as I iterate over a set of this typedef'ed objects it would be useful to print the current element. Unfortunately, boost's templated nature makes the output very uncomfortable to read:

> (gdb) p server
>
> $11 = (const mpn::SER_ID &) @0x756660:
>   {, std::allocator >,
>   boost::detail::empty_base > >> =
>   {, std::allocator >,
>   boost::detail::empty_base > > >> =
>   {, std::allocator >,
>   boost::detail::empty_base > >> =
>   {,
>   std::allocator >, boost::detail::empty_base >> =
>   {,
>   std::allocator >, boost::equality_comparable2,
>   std::allocator >, boost::detail::empty_base > >> =
>   {,
>   std::allocator >, boost::detail::empty_base >> =
>   {> = {}, }, }, }, }, }, }, t = "B"...}

Is there a way of somehow casting the object to a string (which C++ allows with a `static_cast`) and print it normally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` includes the underlying object as the attribute [`t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp) of the typedef:

```
(gdb) p server.t
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of somehow casting the object to a string

Yes: you need to define a pretty printer for it. [Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Writing-a-Pretty_002dPrinter.html). [Example](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524).